# Why the app crashed while setting arguments for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I’m trying to get the arguments transferred from an activity to a fragment, to put into another. The app crashed and said that problem of inflating.

**This my error log :**

```
09-26 09:22:03.968    1524-1524/com.example.user.unchained E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.unchained, PID: 1524
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.unchained/com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

**The concerned part of code**

```
    final Fragment hf = new HeaderFragment();

    Bundle i = getArguments();
    Bundle ii = new Bundle();

    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);


    mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);

    ii.putString("Id",i.getString("Id"));
    ii.putString("Name",i.getString("Name"));
    ii.putString("ImgUrl",i.getString("ImgUrl"));

    hf.setArguments(ii);

    header.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {}
        @Override public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, hf)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: make sure that your activity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: The activity in which you are showing the fragment

Comment: My activity already implements ActionBarActivity impossible to add some other classes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not specifying the root View.

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html):

> public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)
>
> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified
>   xml resource. Throws InflateException if there is an error.
>
> Parameters
>   resource =    ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)
>
> root =    Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy. Returns The root View of the inflated hierarchy.
>
> If root was supplied, this is the root View; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

Since you didn't define a root View in either statement, you are going from `header` as your root View and then immediately switching to `footer` as the root View.

Comment: Ok, I understand but why when I don't add the Bundle part its work very well, and in the other case the app crashed what is the relation between the two

Comment: Which bundle causes problems?

Comment: I guess it's the Bundle that I get, probably it's null